# The vscode file path cannot use "cmd + click" in the output panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

Only the first of several paths in the output panel can be clicked.

[image]

I tried to print the same path myself, but I can’t click.

[image]

Is this a bug or does the output need to be processed?

I found the problem with me, because I used `mimetypes` in `package.json`

```json
"languages": [
    {
        "id": "output-test",
        "mimetypes": [
            "text/x-code-output"
        ],
        "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
    }
],
"grammars": [
    {
        "language": "output-test",
        "scopeName": "source.text",
        "path": "./syntaxes/output-test.tmLanguage.json"
    }
],
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/586#issuecomment-758642272
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
Printing the path in the format of `vscode.Uri` is clickable, although this is not what I really want.
I solved this problem and need to register a DocumentLinkProvider [DocumentLinkProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentLinkProvider)

Can refer to https://github.com/93Akkord/vscode-output-link-to-file.